# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS gigabit ethernet r8153 not recognised

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, usb, ethernet

What do I do with my USB Ethernet non-recognition problem? Is this a driver issue?

I have two r8153 based USB Ethernet adaptors and they both have the same issue. One is a normal USB and the other is USB-c. The adaptors also have three additional USB ports which work fine. Only Ethernet ports are affected.

Running lsusb gives;

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0bda:8153 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
```

This is what comes up in `dmesg`:

```
[17637.643654] r8152 2-2.3:1.0 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): Unknown version 0x6010
[17637.643663] r8152 2-2.3:1.0 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): Unknown Device
```

> uname -a
>   Linux dave-XPS-13-9360 4.4.0-124-generic #148-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 2 >13:00:18 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

The new Ethernet port doesn't come up in `ifconfig`.

I have tried two similar r8153 gigabit adaptors on two separate installations of 16.04LTS one on a Dell XPS 13 and one on a homebrew desktop PC. Neither system was able to use the adaptor.

Can I fix this with a new driver or an updated kernel?
Do I just wait for 18.04LTS upgrade?

Comment: similar here.  

    [ 3073.744087] r8152 4-1.1:1.0 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): 
    Unknown version 0x6010
    [ 3073.744094] r8152 4-1.1:1.0 (unnamed net_device) (uninitialized): 
    Unknown Device  

on ubuntu 16.04 on Dell XPS 9560

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade from Ubuntu 16.04LTS to 18.04LTS fixes this problem